# MySQL delete records using LIMIT or using WHERE

Tags: mysql, indexing, delete-row

I'm trying to find the best way to delete millions of records in MySQL DB.
I have a table with a PK on ID and an index on 'date' column and my delete queries are like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date < '<today - 6 months>';
```

It's generating a lot of delay on the slave.

I had 2 options:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date < '<today - 6 months>' LIMIT 1000;
```

or

Include further Indexing or using PK for deleting.

I would like to hear your opinions. If using LIMIT won't change the workload or if using PK (in combination with LIMIT) is better.

Comment: Similar approach FOR THIS Solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80695/deleting-data-from-a-large-table-with-replication

Comment: Thanks vishal. I will give this a read and get back to you soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to delete lots of rows, especially in a replication setup, is to walk through the table via the `PRIMARY KEY` in chunks of 1000 rows.

See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) for details.

If this is a recurring task, then a 'time series' `PARTITIONing` is even better.  (Though it won't help until you set up partitioning.)  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: Thank you Rick James! Very insightful view. I tried to follow this way but the APP side would need to redefine the index search logic. Since up until now they based it on date rather than PK (id).

Comment: @JuanCarlos - It's OK to delete based on date, since that is what the business logic wants.  But walk through a non-partitioned table by the PK.  Or `PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(..))` in order to do `DROP PARTITION`.  You have a secondary index on `date`, which leads to a costly bouncing between the index BTree and the Data BTree.